# how to get redhat based nodepools in AKS

Tags: kubernetes, redhat, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

In Aks,the nodepools are coming with Ubuntu based images by-default, whereas our applications are using the base image is based on debian.

So we are planning to use the nodepools provisioned with the redhat based images as these are licensed os images. So will this possible to use redhat based nodepools in AKS cluster for both system and user pools.

Comment: No, it's not possible, unles you want to use something like Openshift on Azure

Comment: By "base image", are you referring to the VM image used for the nodes? Or to the base images of your containers?

Comment: base image for nodes